# Using a static IP for both ingress/egress in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, udp, google-kubernetes-engine, nat

I have a program which I'm trying to run in a Kubernetes cluster.
The program is a server that speaks a non-standard UDP-based protocol.
The protocol mostly consists of short request/reply pairs, similar to DNS.
One major difference from DNS is that both the "server" and the "clients" can send requests, ie. the communication can be initiated by either party.

The clients are embedded devices configured with the server's IP address.
The clients send their requests to this IP.
They also check that incoming messages originate from this IP, discarding messages from other IPs.

My question is how I can use Kubernetes to set up the server such that

1. The server accepts incoming UDP messages on a specific IP.
2. Real client source IPs are seen by the server.
3. Any replies (or other messages) the servers sends have that same IP as their source (so that the clients will accept them).

One thing I have tried that doesn't work is to set up a `Service` with `type: LoadBalancer` and `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` (the latter to preserve source IPs for requirement 2).
This setup fulfills requirements 1 and 2 above, but since outbound messages don't pass through the load balancer, their source IP is that of whatever node the pod containing the server is running on.

I'm running Kubernetes on Google Cloud Platform (GKE).

Comment: Did you try to setup cloud NAT for outbound traffic? https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview  There you can also specify static  IP (the one which has been assigned to your LB) to be used by the NAT gateway.

Comment: @A_Suh Cloud NAT will let you select a static IP for the outbound traffic, but you can't use the same address as assigned to the `LoadBalancer` (it rejects it), so you can't achieve the 'same IP for both inbound and outbound' requirement.

Comment: @Viktor Dahl did you find any solution for this? may be with new dualstack cluster with pod ipv6 and intermediate list of IPs may help

Answer (score -2):

Please verify solution as described in:
1. [Kubernetes..](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/),
c) Source IP for Services with **Type=LoadBalancer**
- expose deployment as: *--type=LoadBalancer*
- set *service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy: '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}'*

Using the image as described in the example "echoserver" is returning my public address.

Comment: When using `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` I do see the original source IPs for icoming traffic. So that works fine. The problem I'm having is how to control the source IP of _outbound_ traffic from my pods. The outbound source IP will be correct on messages that look like replies (due to conntrack), but this doesn't help when the "server" initiates communication.

Comment: Outgoing traffic will be going also through load balancer so from the client perspective will be seeing only your public address not any of the POD ip addresses.
Please elaborate more-  in case if there is some misunderstanding from my point of view

Comment: Outgoing traffic does indeed go through the load balancer in cases when the outgoing message is a reply to a recent incoming message.
However, when a Pod behind the LB decides to send a message to a client without having received a message from that client in a long time, the source IP is wrong.
The outgoing source IP is correct when sending to clients which we have recently received a message from (ie. client still has a conntrack entry, I think something like 30s).
The outgoing source is wrong when we decide to communicate with a client after a long period of silence.

Comment: I'm interested on this. On any external connection only the address of the Load Balancer got to be shown as the outbound peer, even if a long time passes away. Can you please tell if you could solve this issue? Also, what IP address is sent as outbound instead of the LB one?

Comment: The IP of the egress is the IP of the node running your container, so essentially random.